lang=ar changes numbers to Hindu–Arabic
I'm facing an issue when changing the viewing language from English to Arabic in my Angular project.
The lang=ar property for the html tag changes the numbers from 1234567890 to ١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠ which is something I don't want.
Isn't there a way to force the use of English numbers?
I have lots of dynamic cases and scenarios and a custom pipe or directive didn't help!
Also, a function to convert the numbers wouldn't be efficient since I'll have to use it hundreds of times!

Are you sure this is an actual problem related to angular and not because of the browser and/or extensions you are using?

My machine(MacOS Pro) and all browsers are in English, and I don't use any language-related extensions. I'm not sure if others faced this issue on other technologies but I did a basic pure html test and didn't see this issue. The numbers 123 remained 123 even after the html tag used lang=ar.

Please add enough code inside the question to create a [mre]. I can't produce this

After creating a basic Angular project to test, I found out that the lang=ar does not automatically convert the numbers to Hindu–Arabic! It's the font family we're using that does! The font family we use provides default number styles with Hindu–Arabic system so the document uses those. I'll have to find another font family to fix the issue. I'll leave the question in case I find a real solution.

If you find this to be the answer, I suggest self-answering with some details. This is not a font behavior I've encountered before, and finding your answer would be very helpful if I or others encounter this.

After creating a basic Angular project to test, I found out that the lang=ar does not automatically convert the numbers to Hindu–Arabic!
It's the font family we're using that does! The font family we use provides default number styles with Hindu–Arabic system and the document uses those.
I had to find another font family to fix the issue..
I'll leave the question and hopefully someone knows a real solution.

what's your font name?

It's named Swissra
